# Reading PC's Process Memory via Android Device

Tags: android, adb

I've been looking around to see if it possible to read a computer's process memory from a connected Android device. I know ADB allows you to modify things (on your device) via the computer's command line, but in reverse, how much control can you have over your computer. An end goal would be for me to read a process's memory (that's running on my computer) solely from my connected phone or tablet. Is this sort of thing even possible?

EDIT: I was just using ADB as an example. I know it's not capable of doing such a thing. Just trying to explain the concept.

Comment: You need to run code on the PC and connect to that using sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think ADB has any native control for getting information from your host machine.  You could code this functionality yourself, but out of the box, ADB doesn't support this sort of thing.

Bottom line, not possible without customization of the tools.

I don't know of another pre-existing tool that would allow you to read info from a host PC.  It may exist though (check http:/www.xda-developers.com for possible source code to modify to fit your needs).

Comment: Was just ADB as an example. Are there any pre-exsisting queries that would help me? And could the device even handle what it would be reading? I know nothing about processors, but x86 and ARM definitely aren't the same.

Comment: The problem is not getting the device to handle what it would be reading, the problem is getting the device to READ the host machine info (this is not possible with ADB, and I can't think of another pre-existing solution for this).

Answer (score 1):

ADB is really a host-controlled system. There's not a lot you can do from the device except respond to what the host tells you. You could always make an app that send messages to a program on the host computer or use VNC?